# Why does Js intersection observer didnt observe my div when using translateX(-100%)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-animations

My scroll down animation for Html text is not working.I used Js Intersection observer to add a class that will make it slide through to middle from the left side.But it does not add the "show" class(when i deleted the transformX(-100%)  it worked but not as the style i wanted it to be).

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show');
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show'); 
        }
    });
}, {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.5
});


const targetElement = document.querySelector('.hidden');

if (targetElement) {
    observer.observe(targetElement);
}
```

```
.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.show{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```
    <div class="hidden">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's because by doing -100% your element is offscreen and not visible so the intersection observer doesn't trigger

Comment: I have seen people using -100% for animation before is there anything i should add to my codes to work

Comment: if the text doesn't go offscreen it's easy. Not sure how they achieve it otherwise, without a bunch of extra code like https://jsfiddle.net/qxjz1nfr/

Answer (score 0):

I started to use TranslateX(-70%) and it solved